I cannot install flash-attention
I try to run my vector search code but I got this error: ImportError: This modeling file requires the following packages that were not found in your environment: flash_attn. Run pip install flash_attn --no-build-isolation as in the github repository. This error probably occured in this line: model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_dir, trust_remote_code= True).cuda().eval()
There are two ways mentioned in the readme file inside the flash-attn repository. The first one is pip install flash-attn --no-build-isolation and the second one is after cloning the repository, navigating to the hooper folder and run python setup.py install. I tried both but I got this errors all at once: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory, fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory , Failed building wheel for flash-attn, Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (flash-attn). Visual Studio 2022 C++ is installed and I checked for the requirements. Also Torch, TorchAudio etc and Cuda are installed compatible.

Just to make sure - did you install PyTorch, packaging, and ninja as the guide suggested?

Oh, and please provide a [mre].

The "Cannot open include file: 'xxx.h'" message are probably because your system (OS) is missing some native dependencies.  Also note that the PyPi entry says: "Might work for Windows starting v2.3.2 (we've seen a few positive reports) but Windows compilation still requires more testing.".  Are you trying to install on ... Windows?

Yes I installed all the required libraries as the guyide suggested.

Yes I try to install on Windows. I installed Visual Studio 2022 C++ for compiling such files. I checked the Windows 10 SDK , C++ CMake tools for Windows and MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools from the installer. I understood that these files are missing but I don't know how to install.

I cant install it either, at least not on windows. Probably best to install on WSL2 if you dont have linux.
